# I am not able to connect to database during run time

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
package connection;


import java.sql.*;
public class Connection {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Connection con1=null;
        String c="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        Class.forName(c);
        String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@LAPTOP-1CQ5FAGB:1521:XE";
        String user="system";
        String passwd="srpnk";
                 con1=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@LAPTOP-1CQ5FAGB:1521:XE","system","srpnk");
        System.out.println("connected");        
    }

}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to connection.Connection
    at connection.Connection.main(Connection.java:17)
C:\Users\Nandhini\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Are you importing the correct Connection class on the top of you class?

Answer (score 3):

Rename your class, `public class Connection`, it's conflicting with `java.sql.Connection` ...

```
public class Connection { // <-- This is a bad idea

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Connection con1=null;
        // ...
        con1=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@LAPTOP-1CQ5FAGB:1521:XE","system","srpnk");
        System.out.println("connected");        
    }
```

The need to case the result of `DriverManager.getConnection` should have set of alarm bells

(Yes, technically, you could use `java.sql.Connection con1...` bad this is still a bad idea, and could continue to cause no end of issues)